# I Want To Log All Error Message in Postman console

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, postman, postman-collection-runner, postman-testcase

Hi Guys Im New In Postman
I Want To Log All Error Message In Postman Console
i have many error message in response
whats is the code i dont know how log all errors

[This is The Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9i0g.png)

this is my code by the way

[new one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9i0g.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this

```
const errors = _.map(Data.errors, _.property("message"));
console.log(errors);
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: i did it but it faild 
see new uploaded picture

Comment: Oh man, this is `test result`, not `postman console`.  See my updated image.